# What's the difference between "includes" and "joins" in ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the difference between "**includes**" and "**joins**" in ActiveRecord query? Can anyone explain to me with the following two associated models?

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_one :car
end
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`:joins` joins tables together in sql, `:includes` eager loads associations to avoid the n+1 problem (where one query is executed to retrieve the record and then one per association which is loaded).

I suggest you read their sections in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to get more info.

Answer (score 47):

```
stores = Store.joins(:car)
```

This will return all stores for which there is a car. `stores[0].car` will result in another query.

```
stores = Store.includes(:car)
```

This will return all stores, car or no car. `stores[0].car` will *not* result in another query.

```
stores = Store.includes(:car).joins(:car)
```

This will return all stores with a car. `stores[0].car` will *not* result in another query. I wouldn't recommend this for `has_many` relationships, but it works great for `has_one`.

Answer (score 6):

:joins returns read-only objects, :includes does not

:joins uses inner join, :includes uses outer join.

the main reason of :includes is eager loading, to avoid the N+1 problem of loading in attributes of each object using a separate query.

Answer (score 3):

Joins will just join the tables and brings selected fields in return. if you call associations on joins query result, it will fire database queries again

Include will eager load the included associations and add them in memory. Include loads all the included tables attributes. If you call associations on include query result, it wont fire any queries

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR

Joins:

```
a.joins(:b).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"a\".* FROM \"a\" INNER JOIN \"b\" ON \"b\".\"id\" = \"a\".\"b_id\""
```

Includes:

```
a.includes(:b).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"a\".* FROM \"a\"
```

Both:

```
a.includes(:b).joins(:b).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"a\".\"id\" AS t0_r0, \"a\".\"a_field_1\" AS t0_r1, \"a\".\"a_field_2\" AS t0_r2, \"a\".\"a_field_3\" AS t0_r3, \"b\".\"a_field_1\" AS t1_r1, \"b\".\"a_field_2\" AS t1_r2, \"b\".\"a_field_3\" AS t1_r3 FROM \"a\" INNER JOIN \"b\" ON \"b\".\"id\" = \"a\".\"plan_id\""
```

Answer (score 0):

`:joins` is the ActiveRecord version of JOINS, the SQL request.

```
Store.joins(:car).to_sql
=> SELECT stores.* FROM stores INNER JOIN cars ON cars.store_id = categories.id
```

So behind the seen it is an implicit `INNER JOIN`. It will thus indeed return all stores that have a car (because of the `inner_join`, a `left_outer_join` would have had a different behaviour). See more [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_record_querying.html#joins).

Whereas `:includes` is not a query command. It solves the n+1 query issue by `eager_loading` the Car model on the Store model. See more one `eager_loading` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes).

```
stores = Store.includes(:car)
```

will thus return all stores, and allows to do `stores.first.car` without firing a new query.

Answer (score -1):

Join: It uses lazy loading and it performs an inner join. joins to simply add two tables together

Includes: Includes uses eager loading and perform a left outer join and includes can also prevent the N+1 queries.

Comment: The explanation for `join` is not correct. It isn't lazy loading, it's building a SQL join between those two tables. You can modify the join strategy to be inner or left etc. Also, `includes` doesnt do a join, it does another single query per association to fetch the associated relations avoiding 1 query per association or 1+N problem when lazy loading.