# Reduce usage of LEFT JOIN in queries with include

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, left-join

I'm getting very ugly SQL queries with Rails code like one listed below:

```
Facility.includes(:type, :owner_building, :delegated_building, keeper_building, :owner_user, :keeper_user).order('users.name ASC').all
```

It produces:

```
SELECT `facilities`.`id` AS t0_r0, `facilities`.`name` AS t0_r1, `facilities`.`brand` AS t0_r2, `facilities`.`desc` AS t0_r3, `facilities`.`type_id` AS t0_r4, `facilities`.`owner_building_id` AS t0_r5, `facilities`.`keeper_building_id` AS t0_r6, `facilities`.`delegated_building_id` AS t0_r7, `facilities`.`owner_user_id` AS t0_r8, `facilities`.`keeper_user_id` AS t0_r9, `buildings`.`id` AS t1_r0, `buildings`.`name` AS t1_r1, `buildings`.`address` AS t1_r2, `buildings`.`created_at` AS t1_r3, `buildings`.`updated_at` AS t1_r4, `buildings`.`comments` AS t1_r5, `delegated_buildings_facilities`.`id` AS t2_r0, `delegated_buildings_facilities`.`name` AS t2_r1, `delegated_buildings_facilities`.`address` AS t2_r2, `delegated_buildings_facilities`.`created_at` AS t2_r3, `delegated_buildings_facilities`.`updated_at` AS t2_r4, `delegated_buildings_facilities`.`comments` AS t2_r5, `keeper_buildings_facilities`.`id` AS t3_r0, `keeper_buildings_facilities`.`name` AS t3_r1, `keeper_buildings_facilities`.`address` AS t3_r2, `keeper_buildings_facilities`.`created_at` AS t3_r3, `keeper_buildings_facilities`.`updated_at` AS t3_r4, `keeper_buildings_facilities`.`comments` AS t3_r5, `users`.`id` AS t4_r0, `users`.`company_id` AS t4_r1, `users`.`building_id` AS t4_r2, `users`.`login` AS t4_r3, `users`.`name` AS t4_r4, `users`.`role` AS t4_r5, `users`.`email` AS t4_r6, `users`.`comments` AS t4_r7, `users`.`crypted_password` AS t4_r8, `users`.`password_salt` AS t4_r9, `users`.`persistence_token` AS t4_r10, `users`.`perishable_token` AS t4_r11, `users`.`login_count` AS t4_r12, `users`.`failed_login_count` AS t4_r13, `users`.`last_request_at` AS t4_r14, `users`.`current_login_at` AS t4_r15, `users`.`last_login_at` AS t4_r16, `users`.`current_login_ip` AS t4_r17, `users`.`last_login_ip` AS t4_r18, `users`.`created_at` AS t4_r19, `users`.`updated_at` AS t4_r20, `keeper_users_facilities`.`id` AS t5_r0, `keeper_users_facilities`.`company_id` AS t5_r1, `keeper_users_facilities`.`building_id` AS t5_r2, `keeper_users_facilities`.`login` AS t5_r3, `keeper_users_facilities`.`name` AS t5_r4, `keeper_users_facilities`.`role` AS t5_r5, `keeper_users_facilities`.`email` AS t5_r6, `keeper_users_facilities`.`comments` AS t5_r7, `keeper_users_facilities`.`crypted_password` AS t5_r8, `keeper_users_facilities`.`password_salt` AS t5_r9, `keeper_users_facilities`.`persistence_token` AS t5_r10, `keeper_users_facilities`.`perishable_token` AS t5_r11, `keeper_users_facilities`.`login_count` AS t5_r12, `keeper_users_facilities`.`failed_login_count` AS t5_r13, `keeper_users_facilities`.`last_request_at` AS t5_r14, `keeper_users_facilities`.`current_login_at` AS t5_r15, `keeper_users_facilities`.`last_login_at` AS t5_r16, `keeper_users_facilities`.`current_login_ip` AS t5_r17, `keeper_users_facilities`.`last_login_ip` AS t5_r18, `keeper_users_facilities`.`created_at` AS t5_r19, `keeper_users_facilities`.`updated_at` AS t5_r20, `facility_types`.`id` AS t6_r0, `facility_types`.`name` AS t6_r1, `facility_types`.`desc` AS t6_r2, `facility_migrations`.`id` AS t7_r0, `facility_migrations`.`building_id` AS t7_r1, `facility_migrations`.`equipment_id` AS t7_r2, `facility_migrations`.`facility_id` AS t7_r3, `facility_migrations`.`created_at` AS t7_r4
FROM `facilities` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN`buildings` ON `buildings`.`id` = `facilities`.`owner_building_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN`buildings` `delegated_buildings_facilities` ON `delegated_buildings_facilities`.`id` = `facilities`.`delegated_building_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN`buildings` `keeper_buildings_facilities` ON `keeper_buildings_facilities`.`id` = `facilities`.`keeper_building_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN`users` ON `users`.`id` = `facilities`.`owner_user_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN`users` `keeper_users_facilities` ON `keeper_users_facilities`.`id` = `facilities`.`keeper_user_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN`facility_types` ON `facility_types`.`id` = `facilities`.`type_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN`facility_migrations` ON `facility_migrations`.`facility_id` = `facilities`.`id` 
WHERE `facilities`.`id` IN (15, 47, 16, 48, 17, 49, 18, 50, 19, 51, 20, 52) AND ((1=1)) ORDER BY users.name ASC
```

So how can I use LEFT JOIN only for fields on which I have conditions (like ordering) and simple SELECTs for other tables (as includes regularly work when there are no conditions)?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Rails but what does `.all` at the end of your code do?

Comment: Find all - This will return all the records matched by the options used. From here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find

Comment: I think you should use the `.joins()` instead of the `.includes()` for the tables you want to `INNER JOIN`. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861416/whats-the-difference-between-includes-and-joins-in-activerecord-query and the guide:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: I know the difference between includes and joins. I need includes because I want to eager load associations (I use their attributes in views).

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Can you try (if it is possible) to have two `.includes()`, one for `:owner_user` and one for all the rest?

Comment: What would you *prefer* it do? You have a bunch of includes, where do you think the data will come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody seems to have mentioned it yet. There is a method called `preload` which does almost the same as `includes`, except that it uses separate queries instead of left joins.

If you want left outer joins only for sorting/grouping/filtering and not included in your results you might want to use the [squeel gem](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) instead, it supports outer joins in the `joins` method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand the question; But do you mean by Ugly the `Select A as B, X as Y'?

If so, then this is Rails (AR) way of mapping the returned values correctly to their corresponding object(s). Any t0_r* will be mapped to a facility object, any t1_r* will be mapped to a building object, etc...

Using `select` will not help you there.

This query is used by Rails internally, and as far as I remember, other ORMs do the same (Hibernate for instance).

Comment: Correct, Hibernate (or NHibernate) does something very similar.

Comment: Not quite so. Usually AR doesn't make JOINs if there are no conditions on fields of associated tables (it uses separate SELECTs to load associations). What I want is to use JOIN once on `users` table and SELECTs for other associations.

Comment: You're right about the individual statements being used to load associated objects. But, when you use the `order(...)` you're actually ordering `Facility` by users. If it is 2 independent selects - you will end up with an ordered `users` - then a list of facilities (non-ordered) that has an associated users from the first query.

Comment: Tamer is absolutely correct.  Your order by query is causing a single lookup with joins to ensure the child included objects are loaded off the ordered users.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't combine joins(:associations) (or select, group etc) with the eager loading tool "includes(:associations)". So one solution would be to cut your query in 2 which is always better than the O(n) effect of lazy loading or loading a lot of unwanted activerecord objects (very expensive) :

1st get the filtered facility ids without the associations you don't need to load

```
facilities_ids = Facility.select("facilities.id").
                   joins([:conditional_associations, ...]).map(&:id)
```

then use them to filter your eager query with all the goodness of "includes":

```
@facilities = Facility.includes([:loaded_associations]).
                 where(["facilities.id IN (?)", facilities_ids])
```

Comment: It's kind of way that I using now. But I thought there is more clearly way. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Another solution implies you're not instansiating the associations but rather loading them as aliased attributes (which is rather tedious). Also with the help of the excellent gem squeel you can combine inner ans outer joins. would you be interested ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a data model question, not an AR question.  AR is just exposing possible schema design issues.

Personally, I'd investigate why deligated_builds are in a different table than buildings.  They should probably be in the same table, then you could specify which delegated building ID in just a query clause instead of a join.  Same goes for similar _building tables.

Comment: Delegated_buildings are in buildings table. Why did you decide that it is not?

Comment: They why are you joining on buildings like 4 times? because of STI?